my laptop screen not displaying anything
Currently in the process of replacing my laptop screen cuz the old one was starting to artifact like crazy. But after plugging in the new one, nothing displays?
Here is how I plug the screen in:
enter image description here
What's weirder is when I try to plug in the original broken one, that one doesn't even display also!! !  Someone help idk what's going on

Take it to a repair shop and ask a tech to check it.
